# How to call restful service with parameters in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
    I am trying to call a restfull service with a parameter . I am getting "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".
```

This is my code in controller:

```
 getAvailableListFromService:function() { 
     var MemberId = 3;            
     var promise = $http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getAvailableList',MemberId)
                   .success(function(data){
               availableList = data;              
               return availableList ;
           })
                   .error(function(data){                   
                    availableList = 'error';                   
                    return availableList ;   
           });
           return promise;   
        }
```

getAvailableList is a method and memberId is a request parameter.how to pass memberId parameter along with method?

Comment: try ´$http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getAvailableList',{nameOfTheparam: MemberId})´

Answer (score -1):

You need to call it as:

```
$http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getAvailableList', {MemberId: MemberId})
```

Check [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) for more info.